# IF,ELSE statement / Loop and variables assignment: code optimization best practices

Tags: performance, optimization

I have some simple and very basic questions here but yet I would like to have the wind up once forever so I decided to ask for.
Ok, here comes the code and the question within:

is something like

```
for (n=0;n<length;++n) countsc[n]=0;
countsc[x]=1; // x is something
```

better than something like

```
for (n=0;n<length;++n) {
  if (n != x) countsc[n]=0;
  else countsc[n]=1;
}
```

or also

```
for (n=0;n<length;++n) countsc[n]=(n != x ? 0 : 1);
```

in terms of performance and optimization (speed, cpu and memory usage)?
How would it be the convenient way one should measure it, for example, with Javascript and/or with PHP? Would the answer be generally valid for all programming languages or it may differ?

In a similar way, is something like

```
a=0;
if (condition == true) a=1;
```

generally better than

```
if (condition == true) a=1;
else a=0;
```

or also

```
a = (condition == true ? 1 : 0);
```

when condition is usually false?

Comment: First rule of optimization:  **Don't do it.**  Second rule:  **Don't do it _yet_.**

Comment: The condition is loop invariant. Use two loops.

Comment: @Makoto: I'll keep it in mind for sure (Funny :D)

Comment: @wildplasser: wouldn't you explain a little more?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but in general, I don't think there would be a general way to figure this out from static analysis of code.  This is not only going to vary by language, but also possibly by architecture you run it on.  I suspect any half-decent compiler should optimize these so there is little/no difference, but that may be less likely for interpreted languages.

If it really is a performance critical section of code (and you will only know that by profiling), then the best answer you will get will be by profiling and comparing the two candidate code sections on your target architecture, using the relevant language.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the quality of the compiler (or interpreter, if appropriate),

```
for (n=0;n<length;++n) countsc[n]=0;
countsc[x]=1;
```

is easier to optimize, since there are no branches to (mis)predict. The minor duplication of setting `countsc[x]` twice is trivial compared to need to test `n` each iteration and the penalty for a missed branch prediction inside the loop of

```
for (n=0;n<length;++n) {
  if (n != x) countsc[n]=0;
  else countsc[n]=1;
}
```

In terms of branch prediction, your third example with the ternary operator is identical to the second.

However, unless this is a tight inner loop that is either executed frequently and/or for very large values of `length`, it's unlikely to matter which approach you use looking at the overall running time of your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (n=0;n<length;++n) countsc[n]=0;
countsc[x]=1;
```

is the more performant option, assuming comparison and assignment have roughly the same cost.

Similarly,

```
if (condition) a=1; // boolean == true is not pretty
else a=0;
```

should be more performant; you only have one assignment and one jump, while you have up to two assignments and one jump with the alternative version. This version

```
a = (condition == true ? 1 : 0);
```

should be just as good, I expect it is compiled to the same code as the if-else version.

Answer (score 0):

I would think

```
for (n = 0; n < x; ++n)
    countsc[n] = 0;
countsc[x] = 1;
for (n = x + 1; n < length; ++n)
    countsc[n] = 0;
```

Would be better than using the conditional, and you avoid rewriting your countsc[x]. Of course, everything is O(n) and you won't notice any change in the speed in your program.